# Leaflet geoJson mouseover does not work for all polygons

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I have  geojson polygons. Code highlights the polygon on mouse over.  The problem is: for some polygons, the mouse over does not activate; and sometimes I need to move mouse outside polygon and back in a few times to get it to activate.

[image: Mouseover working]
[image: Mouseover not working]

Comment: Please specify your leaflet version, whether you're using canvas or svg for rendering, whether the problem is in one browser or more than one, and a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of a map or a geojson file in which the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: It sounds like your geoJSON file is corrupt. Try validating it at http://geojsonlint.com/

Comment: Thanks for the reply Stephen.  As you suggested, I tried to validate the geoJSON file.  I received the following error "Polygons and MultiPolygons should follow the right-hand rule".  I also tried several other polygon shapefiles converted to geoJSON and received the same error.  I am now looking to see options on how to fix this. Thank you.

Comment: To fix the right hand rule error, check out this nice utility. The geojson files I had properly validated after using this tool. Also note that by default, it will send the processed file to stdout, so pipe it to a file to actually save the results-

https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-rewind